# Test class not covering the wrapper class and giving Invalid field for Contact error

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have below Apex class for which I am trying to write test class, but its not covering the entire class and giving Invalid field for Contact error.

Apex Class

```
public without sharing class LookUpController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<LookupControllerWrapper> getQuerySobj (String queryString){
       String queryParam = queryString.replace('{','\'').replace('}','\'');
        List<SObject> results = Database.query(queryParam);
        String fields = queryParam.substringAfter('SELECT ').substringBefore(' FROM');
        List<String> fieldList = fields.split(',');
        List<LookupControllerWrapper> LCWrapList = new List<LookupControllerWrapper>();
        LookupControllerWrapper lcw ;
        if(results.size() > 0) {
            for(SObject sObj : results){
                lcw = new LookupControllerWrapper();
                for(integer i =0; i<fieldList.size();i++){
                    if(fieldList.get(i) != null){
                        switch on i {
                            when 0 {
                                lcw.textValue0 = (String)sObj.get(fieldList.get(i));
                            }
                            when 1 {
                                lcw.textValue1 = (String)sObj.get(fieldList.get(i));
                            }
                            when 2 {
                                lcw.textValue2 = (String)sObj.get(fieldList.get(i));
                            }
                            when 3 {
                                lcw.textValue3 = (String)sObj.get(fieldList.get(i));  
                            }
                            when 4 {
                                lcw.textValue4 = (String)sObj.get(fieldList.get(i));  
                            }
                        } 
                    }      
                }
              LCWrapList.add(lcw);
            }
        }
         return LCWrapList;
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public with sharing class LookUpController_Test {
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData(){
         final Account acc = TestData.newAccount(1,'Talent');
        final Contact ct = TestData.newContact(acc.id, 1, 'Talent');
        insert ct;
    }
    @isTest
    public static void checkQuerySobj(){
        Test.startTest();
        final contact con = [select FirstName from contact limit 1];
        String queryString = 'Select id,name,Email,Phone,MailingStreet from contact';
        List<LookupControllerWrapper> resultString = LookUpController.getQuerySobj(queryString);
        System.assertEquals('testcon1',con.FirstName);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that

`subStringAfter` and `substringBefore` are case sensitive

So

```
String fields = queryParam.substringAfter('SELECT ').substringBefore(' FROM');
```

fails when given input of `'Select id,name,Email,Phone,MailingStreet from contact'`

You could resolve this by uppercasing the input arg in `getQueryObj()` before doing the substrings.

Comment: This resolved my issue, thank you